Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects
There are a couple of articles about this issue already, but none of them solve my issue.
I have two sets of Python dataframes (df_A1, df_A2 and df_B1, df_B2) and I want to combine the A's together and the B's together. I can concat the A's just fine, but the B's give me the error 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects'. There are a couple of causes that I found online but that won't work for me.

Duplicate column names.
The B dataframes have indeed columns with the same name, but the A dataframes have this as well and it works just fine with that. So this shouldn't be an issue in the same code. Also, I used df.index.is_unique which returns True for all dataframes, but of course df.columns.is_unique returns False.

Empty columnnames.
I had that as well and made sure all empty columnnames are now filled using [item or '_empty_' for item in <list_columns>]

Using ignore_index=True.
Did that for the A's and B's, the A's are still working with concat and the B's still don't.


I have the traceback here:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\utils.py:209 in exec_encapsulate_locals
    exec_fun(compile(code_ast, filename, "exec"), globals)

  File c:\<path>\python_script.py:168
    df_B = pd.concat([df_B1 , df_B2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:395 in concat
    return op.get_result()

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:680 in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3885 in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Don't describe and show. read notice: [mre]

Yeah well I cannot show the data (columns or information) itself, so I don't have a choice here.

You can create 2 small simplified df from your data but changing what need to be changed. Check that you still have the same issue with these fake data and if so add them to your question.
